# VSTS build fails to checkout git submodules

Tags: git, build, azure-devops, git-submodules

I'm trying to build a project in VSTS that includes a git submodule.
The build is configured to checkout submodules so I assume that it should checkout the submodule. When I run the build the "Get sources" step shows that the module has been checked out.

```
 Submodule path '*************': checked out '0740556614e1cf87da0873b1982b03aaf0b3886d'
```

However in the "Build solution" step claims that it can not find the files. When I search for the files on the build server I don't see the module that should have been checked out. So that explains why the build can't find them.

What I don't understand is why it claims to have checked it out, but it really didn't. The build is a clone of another build definition that does exactly the same with the same git submodule for another repository and in that build it works just fine.

does anyone know what the issue might be?

Here is the build log:

```
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7198274Z ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7198274Z   Building solution configuration "dev|any cpu".
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7823299Z Project "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\Deployment.sln" (1) is building "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\AzureResourceGroup\AzureResourceGroup.deployproj" (2) on node 1 (Publish target(s)).
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7823299Z PrepareForBuild:
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7823299Z   Creating directory "bin\Dev\".
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7823299Z   Creating directory "obj\Dev\".
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7979556Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3608,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Dev\AzureResourceGroup.exe" because it was not found.
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7979556Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3608,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Dev\AzureResourceGroup.exe" because it was not found. [D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\AzureResourceGroup\AzureResourceGroup.deployproj]
2017-10-16T11:18:46.7979556Z Done Building Project "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\AzureResourceGroup\AzureResourceGroup.deployproj" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
2017-10-16T11:18:46.8135812Z Project "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\Deployment.sln" (1) is building "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\Scripts\Scripts.pssproj" (3) on node 1 (Publish target(s)).
2017-10-16T11:18:46.8135812Z PrepareForBuild:
2017-10-16T11:18:46.8135812Z   Creating directory "bin\Debug\".
2017-10-16T11:18:46.8135812Z   Creating directory "obj\Debug\".
2017-10-16T11:18:47.0635934Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3608,5): Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\MyApplication.exe" because it was not found.
2017-10-16T11:18:47.0635934Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3608,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\MyApplication.exe" because it was not found. [D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\Scripts\Scripts.pssproj]
2017-10-16T11:18:47.0635934Z Done Building Project "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\Scripts\Scripts.pssproj" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
2017-10-16T11:18:47.0635934Z Done Building Project "D:\agent4\_work\1\s\**********.Deployment\Deployment.sln" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
2017-10-16T11:18:47.0635934Z 
2017-10-16T11:18:47.0635934Z Build FAILED.
```

What I also don't understand is why it is looking for .exe files because it shouldn't and they aren't there.

Comment: What's the permission scope for the build definition? You say it's checking out from another repo, if that lives inside another Team Project, you may need to set the Build Definition's permissions to be scoped to the Collection.

Comment: Can you show the detail build log here?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I included a piece of the build log

Comment: @RonaldRozema Does the file `AzureResourceGroup.exe` original exist in the submodule repo or it's the build artifacts after building the project? Did you select **Checkout submodules** option in Get sources step?